# Reference for ramification and branch loci for quasiprojective varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Let $\theta: V \to W$ be a dominant morphism of irreducible quasiprojective varieties $V$, $W$ of the same dimension, say $n$.

There is a number $\deg(\theta)$ such that $\{w \in W:|\theta^{-1}(w)| = \deg(\theta)\}$ is constructible and Zariski dense in $W$. The *branch locus* of $\theta$ is $Br_\theta = \{ w\in W: |\theta^{-1}(w)| \neq \deg(\theta)\}$. The *ramification locus* of $\theta$ is $Ram_\theta = \theta^{-1}(Br_\theta)$. The branch and ramification loci are constructible and of dimension $<n$.

I am looking for a reference for the definitions of branch and ramification loci, the degree $\deg(\theta)$ and their aforementioned properties. I know that these properties follow easily from the fibre dimension theorem, which also implies that $\deg(\theta)$ is the size of generic fibres of $\theta$. Moreover, I found definitions of ramification and branch loci for schemes in the literature (e.g. Vakil's notes), but citing those would be more confusing as the above facts are quite simple. So I need a reference in the context of classical algebraic geometry.